# Deadlock when two condition objects assigned to lock object

Tags: java, multithreading, locking, deadlock, conditional-statements

For some reason, my program deadlocks when I assign both condition objects to my lock object. When I comment out one of the condition objects, it does not deadlock. Is there something I'm missing when it comes to assigning multiple condition objects to a single lock object? The entirety of my code below just in case you wish to look at it in its entirety. Thank you so much for all your help and time in advance!

Focus on my BankAccount class which contains the lock and condition objects as instance fields:

```
            import java.util.concurrent.locks.Condition;
            import java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock;
            import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;

            public class BankAccount
            {
                public static final double MAX_BALANCE = 100000;

                private double balance;
                private Lock balanceChangeLock;
                private Condition sufficientFundsCondition; // signals that funds > 0 to allow withdrawal
                private Condition lessThanMaxBalanceCondition; // signals that balance < 100000 to allow more deposits

                /**
                 * Constructs a bank account with a zero balance
                 */
                public BankAccount()
                {
                    balance = 0;
                    balanceChangeLock = new ReentrantLock();
                    sufficientFundsCondition = balanceChangeLock.newCondition();
                    lessThanMaxBalanceCondition = balanceChangeLock.newCondition();
                }

                /**
                 * deposits money into the bank account
                 * @param amount the amount to deposit
                 * @throws InterruptedException
                 */
                public void deposit(double amount) throws InterruptedException
                {
                    balanceChangeLock.lock();
                    try
                    {
                        while(balance + amount > MAX_BALANCE)
                            lessThanMaxBalanceCondition.await();
                        System.out.print("Depositing " + amount);
                        double newBalance = balance + amount;
                        System.out.println(", new balance is " + newBalance);
                        balance = newBalance;
                        sufficientFundsCondition.signalAll();
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        balanceChangeLock.unlock();
                    }
                }

                /**
                 * withdraws money from the bank account
                 * @param amount the amount to withdraw
                 * @throws InterruptedException
                 */
                public void withdraw(double amount) throws InterruptedException
                {
                    balanceChangeLock.lock();
                    try
                    {
                        while (balance < amount)
                            sufficientFundsCondition.await();
                        System.out.print("Withdrawing " + amount);
                        double newBalance = balance - amount;
                        System.out.println(", new balance is " + newBalance);
                        balance = newBalance;
                        lessThanMaxBalanceCondition.signalAll();
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        balanceChangeLock.unlock();
                    }
                }

                /**
                 * gets the current balance of the bank account
                 * @return the current balance
                 */
                public double getBalance()
                {
                    return balance;
                }
            }
```

My Runnable objects:

```
            /**
             * a deposit runnable makes periodic deposits to a bank account
             */
            public class DepositRunnable implements Runnable
            {
                private static final int DELAY = 1;

                private BankAccount account;
                private double amount;
                private int count;

                /**
                 * constructs a deposit runnable
                 * @param anAccount the account into which to deposit money
                 * @param anAmount the amount to deposit in each repetition
                 * @param aCount the number of repetitions
                 */
                public DepositRunnable(BankAccount anAccount, double anAmount, int aCount)
                {
                    account = anAccount;
                    amount = anAmount;
                    count = aCount;
                }

                public void run()
                {
                    try
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i <= count; i++)
                        {
                            account.deposit(amount);
                            Thread.sleep(DELAY);
                        }
                    }
                    catch (InterruptedException exception)
                    {
                    }
                }
            }
```

..

```
            /**
             * a withdraw runnable makes periodic withdrawals from a bank account
             */
            public class WithdrawRunnable implements Runnable
            {
                private static final int DELAY = 1;

                private BankAccount account;
                private double amount;
                private int count;

                /**
                 * constructs a withdraw runnable
                 * @param anAccount the account from which to withdraw money
                 * @param anAmount the amount to deposit  in each repetition
                 * @param aCount the number of repetitions
                 */
                public WithdrawRunnable(BankAccount anAccount, double anAmount, int aCount)
                {
                    account = anAccount;
                    amount = anAmount;
                    count = aCount;
                }

                public void run()
                {
                    try
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i <= count; i++)
                        {
                            account.withdraw(amount);
                            Thread.sleep(DELAY);
                        }
                    }
                    catch (InterruptedException exception)
                    {
                    }
                }
            }
```

And my main method class where I construct my Thread objects and such:

```
            /**
             * this program runs threads that deposit and withdraw money from the same bank account
             */
            public class BankAccountThreadRunner
            {
                public static void main(String[] args)
                {
                    BankAccount account = new BankAccount();

                    final double AMOUNT = 10000;
                    final int REPETITIONS = 10;
                    final int DEPOSIT_THREADS = 10;
                    final int WITHDRAW_THREADS = 2;

                    for (int i = 0; i < DEPOSIT_THREADS; i++)
                    {
                        DepositRunnable deposits = 
                                new DepositRunnable(account, AMOUNT, REPETITIONS);
                        Thread depositThread = new Thread(deposits);
                        depositThread.run();
                    }

                    for (int i = 0; i < WITHDRAW_THREADS; i++)
                    {
                        WithdrawRunnable withdrawals = 
                                new WithdrawRunnable(account, AMOUNT, REPETITIONS);
                        Thread withdrawThread = new Thread(withdrawals);
                        withdrawThread.run();
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are only using one thread. At no point does your code start or create any additional threads. You create `Runnable` objects, but then you never launch any threads but instead call their `run` methods from the main thread!

You should never call a `Runnable` object's `run()` method (unless you actually want to run the code in the calling thread). See [this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/runthread.html) for more information.

Comment: But I have two thread objects: withdrawThread and depositThread

Comment: Oh! I see now! My god! So subtle!

Comment: Just for completeness, it's OK to call `run()` if you just want to execute a piece of code - that is if you're using the `Runnable` interfaced for something other than threaded execution

Answer (score 1):

A deadlock can only occur when there are *two* resources that can be "locked" for exclusive access (I'll call them "locks", although they may be any such resource), with a usage pattern like this:

- Process `A` intends to obtain locks `X` then `Y`
- Process `B` intends to obtain locks `Y` then `X`

If process `A` obtains lock `X` and process `B` obtains lock `Y`, you'll have a deadlock.

A version of this is what you (must) have going on here.

Comment: So this would be an issue in my BankAccount class?

Comment: There are more complex and less obvious scenarios, but that is, indeed, the gist of it.

Comment: Thank you so much, all of you guys!

Comment: @HotLicks I guess I was emphasising that it couldn't happen with just one lock

Answer (score 0):

The fact is that whenever you allow a thread to lock more than one resource at a time and don't take any precautions (and there actually is multi-threading going on), deadlocks are a possibility (and will almost certainly occur eventually).

There are basically two options for dealing with deadlocks:

1. Detect deadlocks and "break" them.
2. Use a "priority" scheme where locks must be acquired in a given order.

Detecting deadlocks can be accomplished in the simple case using a deadlock trace mechanism, where, when a thread waits on a lock, it examines the locks held by the thread for which it's waiting to see if any (directly or indirectly) lead back to the current thread.

Deadlocks can also be detected with a timeout mechanism, though this scheme generally can't distinguish between a deadlock and a long-running operation.

In either case, when a deadlock is detected one or more threads are forced to give up some or all of their locks (which may require some sort of "rollback" mechanism for partial changes they have made).

The simplest "priority" scheme is to only allow one lock to be held at a time.  Slightly more complicated is requiring all locks to be acquired at once.  A true priority scheme assigns different lockable resources to different categories, and then "orders" the categories in a "priority order" such that you can't acquire any locks on category N if you already hold any locks in category N or a category > N.

But, unfortunately, any scheme (except maybe the basic timeout scheme) can be undone by threads that communicate with messages and which wait on messages from other threads.  If you think about it, this is conceptually identical to waiting to obtain a lock the other thread has.